# Change "Q" quarterly data to custom "kv" in Matplotlib timeline chart on x axis Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have done the following timeline chart in Python. Where the data is in quarterly format by datetimeindex. However, I need to translate the graph into my local language and therefore replace "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" with "kv1", "kv2", "kv3", "kv4". Is this possible? So I need the x axsis to be kv3, kv4, kv1 2022, kv2 instead of Q3, Q4, Q1 2022, Q2 and so fourth.

[image]

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import pandas
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "Arial"
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = "Arial"

categories = ['Car','Train','Boat', 'Plane', 'Walk' ]

cat_dict = dict(zip(categories, range(1, len(categories)+1)))

val_dict = dict(zip(range(1, len(categories)+1), categories))

dates = pandas.DatetimeIndex(freq='Q', start='2021-09-30', end='2023-12-31')
values = [random.choice(categories) for _ in range(len(dates))]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=values, index=dates, columns=['category'])

df['plotval'] = [float('NaN'),1,1,3,1,float('NaN'),5,2,1,float('NaN')]
df['plotval'][0] = np.nan

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 4,3.5
plt.figure(dpi=1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df['plotval'].plot(ax=ax, style='^',color='darkblue', label = "Renteheving", markersize=12)

ax.margins(0.2)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: val_dict.get(x)))
plt.yticks( weight = 'bold')
```

I tried to add

```
plt.xlabel(["kv1", "kv2", "kv3", "kv4"])
```

Which gave me

[image]

Help is as always highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your code:

```
# Call draw to populate tick labels
plt.draw()

# Change major labels
new_major_labels = []
for label in ax.get_xticklabels(minor=False):
    s = label.get_text()
    label.set_text(s.replace('Q', 'kv'))
    new_major_labels.append(label)
    
ax.set_xticklabels(new_major_labels, minor=False)

# Change minor labels
new_minor_labels = []
for label in ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True):
    s = label.get_text()
    label.set_text(s.replace('Q', 'kv'))
    new_minor_labels.append(label)
    
ax.set_xticklabels(new_minor_labels, minor=True)
```

It throws a warning which I don't understand, but I think it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not test it because I can't reproduce your graph, but this should work:

```
D = {'Q1':'kv1', 'Q2':'kv2', 'Q3':'kv3', 'Q4':'kv4'}  # define a dictionnary to replace labels

labels = [i.get_text() for i in ax.get_xticklabels()]  # get former labels
labels = [i if i not in D.keys() else D[i] for i in labels]  # replace it if in dictionnary
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)  # apply the new labels
```